# Insert geometry with SQL*Loader in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, gis

I have a table in Oracle with this format:

```
create table MY_USER.MY_TABLE(
    POINT                   SDO_GEOMETRY,
    "date"                  TIMESTAMP(6),
    DEVICE                  NUMBER(10)
)
```

Now I want to use SQL*Loader to insert data in this table. My problem is mainly about the SDO_GEOMETRY column. I want to do this insertion on a fast pace, for example inserting 5000 data in less than 500 milliseconds.

I have tried this control file and it worked without errors, however it was so time-consuming (it took almost 2 seconds for inserting 5000 rows):

```
options(skip=1)
load data
infile '/path/data.csv'
append into table MY_USER.MY_TABLE
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS (
    point COLUMN OBJECT (
         SDO_GTYPE,
         SDO_SRID,
         SDO_POINT COLUMN OBJECT (
            X  INTEGER EXTERNAL,
            Y  INTEGER EXTERNAL
         )
    ),
    "date"  TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF',
    device  INTEGER EXTERNAL,
)
```

And my data file was something like this:

```
sdo_gtype, sdo_srid, x, y, date, device 
2001,3857,10000,10000,2023-04-10 16:00:00.000,100000
```

As I said, this method worked fine, but it was too slow. I think that by using the SDO_GEOMETRY constructor directly, the performance can be better. So I tried to do something like this in my control file: (I also omitted 2001 and 3857 from my data file)

```
...
point "SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 3857, SDO_POINT_TYPE(:x, :y, NULL), NULL, NULL)",
...
```

But this method didn't work and said bad datatype for POINT column.

Does anyone have any idea or experience that may help me? I want a fast way to insert this bulk of data to my table. I want something similar to PostgreSQL `COPY` command in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert using PLSQL and your version of Oracle is Oracle 10g or later
then you can use `BULK COLLECT INTO`  and to insert DML use `FOR ALL`.

Please refer to this blog as a reference :
https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall

Comment: I don't want to exchange data stored in the database into another table in the same database. The source of my data is a RabbitMQ queue and I receive the messages from the queue and then I try to insert them from my Java application to the database. I think that the approach you mentioned works only for moving a huge bulk of data from an existing table into another table.